# Windows Phone RichTextBlock image inside a hyperlink

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, richtextblock

I am developing application on Windows Phone 8.1. I am using RichTextBlock to display rich content: text, images, hyperlinks.

**Here is how to create image for rich text block**:

```
new InlineUIContainer
{
    Child = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://img.jpg", UriKind.Absolute))
    }
};
```

I tried to create hyperlink with image inside like that:

```
hyperlink.Inlines.Add(CreateImageInlineUIContainer(...));
```

This line of code throws an exception:

```
ArgumentException: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Am I missing something? Are there any other ways to add hyperlink with image to a RichTextBlock?